# Need help..How to read integer number from the string

Tags: arduino

I am new to programming. I am getting string in Arduino program.

How to extract only integer ("240") from below string and convert into int.

```
GET /?LED=240&submit=Change+Pin+5%21 HTTP/1.1
```

I have tried to read using `index of()`, but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below C++ logic.

```html
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T>
T StringToNumber(const std::string &Text)
{
    std::istringstream ss(Text);
    T result;
    ss >> result;
    if(ss.fail())
    {
        result = 0;
        assert(0);
    }

    return result;
}

int GetLEDNumber(const std::string& input)
{
    int retValue = 0;
    const std::string startPattern = "LED=";
    const std::string endPattern = "&submit";

    size_t firstPos = input.find(startPattern);
    if(std::string::npos != firstPos)
    {
        size_t endPos = input.find(endPattern);
        if (std::string::npos != endPos)
        {
            size_t positionOfLedNum = firstPos + startPattern.length();
            size_t sizeOfLedNum = endPattern.length() - positionOfLedNum;
            std::string ledNumber = input.substr(positionOfLedNum, sizeOfLedNum);

            retValue = StringToNumber<int>(ledNumber);
        }
    }

    return retValue;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "GET /?LED=240&submit=Change+Pin+5%21 HTTP/1.1";
    std::cout << GetLEDNumber(input) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```